# How to make 2 color represent positive and negative word cloud in d3.js from csv

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I have a csv file

```
`[Name,Frequency,Sentiment hijacked,664,negative pay,267,negative gang,191,negative knives,120,negative planes,64,negative shut,60,negative police,60,negative russia,58,negative term,57,negative fulfil,55,negative agendas,55,negative malicious,55,negative unaccounted,55,negative misused,55,negative one,51,negative crashlands,48,negative two,43,positive befo,41,negative airpo,36,negative dam,36,negative shootout,36,positive following,35,positive ality,34,negative india,34,negative need,34,negative news,29,negative used,26,negative series,25,negative robbers,24,negative got,21,negative twitter,18,negative back,16,negative people,16,negative car,16,negative terrorists,16,negative purpose,16,negative think,15,negative]`
```

consist of 3 data Name, Frequency and Sentiment

I want to create a word cloud in rapid d3.js that have to color which is blue and red. This color depend on either the Sentiment is 'positive' or 'negative'.

The word cloud that I have now is in black color. How can I make it change to red and blue?

This is my coding:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Word Cloud~</title>

  <script src="d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="d3.layout.cloud.js"></script>
  
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   var width = 1050,
    height = 800;
   
   var leaderScale = d3.scale.linear().range([30,90]);
   
    var fill = d3.scale.category20();
    d3.csv("file.csv", function(data) {
     var leaders = data
         .map(function(d) {return { text: d.Name, size: +d.Frequency,  sentiment: d.Sentiment }; })
         .sort(function(a,b) { return d3.descending(a.size, b.size); })
         .slice(0, 100);
     
     leaderScale.domain([
      d3.min(leaders, function(d) { return d.size; }),
      d3.max(leaders, function(d) { return d.size; })
     ]);
      
        d3.layout.cloud().size([width, height])
        .words(loadWords())
        .words(leaders)
          .padding(0)
          //.rotate(function() { return ~~(Math.random() * 2) * 90; })
          .font("Impact")
          .fontSize(function(d) {return leaderScale(d.size); })
          
          .on("end", drawCloud)
          .start();
        
        function loadWords(leaders){
            var word1 = {
                    text: 'Name',
                    size: 'Frequency',
                    sentiment : 'Sentiment',
                    //if(sentiment : 'positive')
                    color:'#FF00FF'
                    };
            var word2 = {
                    text: 'Name',
                    size: 'Frequency',
                    sentiment : 'Sentiment',
                    //if(sentiment : 'negative')
                    color:'#3498DB'
                    };
            return [word1,word2]
            }
        
        function fillColor(d,i){
            return d.color;
        }

        function drawCloud(words) {
          console.log(words);
          d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate("+(width/2)+","+(height/2)+")")
            .selectAll("text")
            .data(words)
            .enter().append("text")
            .style("font-size", function(d) {
              return d.size + "px";
            })
            .style("fill", function(d) { 
                 console.log(d); 
                 return (d.sentiment == "positive" ? "red" : "black"); })
            .style("font-family", "Impact")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
              return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
            })
            .text(function(d) {
              return d.text;
            });
        }
      });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The function fillcolor is setting the color to the text but i didnt see any place where you set the d.color the color.

```
function fillColor(d,i){
            return d.color;
        }
```

You can do something like this instead when you making the text:

```
 .style("fill", function(d) { 
                 console.log(d); 
                 return (d.sentiment == "positive" ? "red" : "black"); })
```

Working code in fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/y6fxbu9c/7/

Comment: Thank you for your response. How can i set the color? As i can see in fiddle. You put it in css part. Do I need to add the css part in my code body or create a css file with that code? I try to create a new css file and put a link in the <head> like this : <link rel="stylesheet" href="wordcloud.css">  </head> but no changes in my word cloud and still all word colored in black

Comment: No I didnt put anything in the CSS part.
I have removed the CSS in this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/y6fxbu9c/8/
You don't need to add anything in the CSS, all you need to do is to add the style fill as i have illustrated above, same is done in the fiddle code.

Comment: I change my coding as u instructed me in my question to but I still got my word colored in black.

Comment: Have you also removed this line
.style("fill",fillColor)

Comment: I removed .style("fill",fillColor) but still got the same result. Is it because that I put the color variable in the loadWords() function?

Comment: inside your function loadWords setiment : 'Sentiment', seems to be a typo should have been this sentiment : 'Sentiment'

Comment: I think the typo did no effect the result because it is still the same.

Comment: Strange! when you try to inspect do you see the fill style on the text element?

Comment: i try to inspect the text element. I should look into the object right? this is what i got bjectfont: "Impact"hasText: trueheight: 123padding: 0rotate: -60sentiment: NaNsize: 30style: "normal"text: "twitter"weight: "normal"width: 128x: 127x0: -64x1: 64xoff: 224y: -140y0: -47y1: 60yoff: 582

Comment: 2 things from here *sentiment* is getting set into the style which should not have happened...other thing is that the *fill* is not getting set as style...

Comment: I found where the problem in my code. The problem with the fill is that the sentiment is not recognized making d.sentiment == "positive" is always false. That's why my word cloud is black. This is because  in my mapping function above i put sentiment = +d.Sentiment. it should be just sentiment = d.Sentiment as +d is for integer. Thank you so much for your help :)  .Can i ask your opinion how can i improve the size of the word in the word cloud? Because as u can see before. I have one word that is large and the other is average in size whereby it should be differ depending on their frequency.

Comment: Great! that it worked for you..
The size of the word is handled by this section where we define the font size...you can regulate it by your algorithm _.fontSize(function(d) {return leaderScale(d.size); })_